# How to show daily notification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter_local_notifications to show notifications. I am able to see notifications for the same day but as the day changes, I am not able to see any notification.

```
  static void showScheduledNotification(
  {int id = 0, String title, String body, String payload, Time time, List<int> days}) async {
print(time.hour.toString() + " : hour time");
print(days.toString() + " : minute time");

_notification.zonedSchedule(
    id,
    title,
    body,
    _scheduleWeekly(time, days: days),
    await _notificationDetails(),
    payload: payload,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime,
    );
```

}

```
 static tz.TZDateTime _scheduleWeekly(Time time, {List<int> days}) {
tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = _scheduleDaily(time);
while (!days.contains(scheduledDate.weekday)) {
  scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
}
return scheduledDate;
```

}

Comment: i guess you are only scheduling once unless there is loop you did not include